# Display table results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display results from a database onto my site. I have one entry in the database, and the result of that entry should be a "1". However, when I run the following code, it returns "1111111111111..." and continues to load ones. If there are 4 entries, I want the results to be displayed like:

1
2
3
4

I have looked around on this forum and others but cannot find anywhere where somebody had the same problem, and my code looks similar to the others. What did I do wrong?

functions.php:

```
$sqlgroup = mysql_query ("SELECT groupid FROM groups");
$grouprow = mysql_fetch_array ($sqlgroup);
```

Settings.php:

```
<?php while( ($row = $grouprow))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['groupid']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
} ?>
```

Comment: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlgroup))`

Comment: This produces the same results.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use mysql, use mysqli isntead:

```
$sqlgroup = mysqli_query ("SELECT groupid FROM groups");


while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($sqlgroup))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['groupid']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: When I change it to mysqli, my entire site gets an internal 500 server error

Comment: This might be helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034553/unknown-internal-500-error-php

Comment: The code to connect to my database is `self::$dbh = new \PDO("mysql:dbname=". self::$config['db']['name'] .";host=". self::$config['db']['host'] .";port=". self::$config['db']['port'], self::$config['db']['username'], self::$config['db']['password']);`, do I need to change the "mysql" to "mysqli" in this case, or no since it is PDO?